# no Push Notification when App is inactive PubNub

Tags: android, xamarin.android, pubnub

I am using xamarin and I configured FCM in my app and also PubNub.

in onStart i RemovePushNotificationsFromChannels with old token and adding AddPushNotificationsOnChannels with new token inside OnTokenRefresh(). when my app is active push notification working fine. but the problem is when the app becomes inactive no more notification coming to my device but when I tested firebase console and send a test push its coming and I also monitoring this from PubNub console by subscribing with {channel-name}-pndebug. I found few moments after when app became inactive in my debug console printing this `"GCM Error: NotRegistered Devices: {token}"`. I searched and found this [article](https://support.pubnub.com/support/solutions/articles/14000043534-can-my-android-app-receive-messages-while-inactive-) but with [Android Oreo Background Execution Limits](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Pumf_4yjTMc) says can't call start services from the background. sorry if I getting this wrong.

how can I achieve what I am trying to do?

Comment: @CraigConover https://support.pubnub.com/support/tickets/5948

Comment: @CraigConover added log file into my ticket

Comment: Thanks but no need to comment further here. I see it faster in the ticket and SO will tell us to stop having a chat session in comments. ;)

Comment: not yet. working on it

Comment: Hi, by `"GCM Error: NotRegistered Devices: {token}"`, you can uninstall the app, and reinstall it, then you will get a new token. You can try it.

Comment: @JoeLv-MSFT i tried it didn't work.

Comment: If your app is background, you can use `Data messages` not `Notification message`.

Comment: @JoeLv-MSFT i don't understand then why i getting notification send by using firebase console and not from pubnub. after app goes background firebase remember my device but pubnub saying 'GCM Error: NotRegistered Devices: {token}'

Comment: Can you share your code that listens for the push notifications and gets the message?

Comment: It's been solved